# R square interpretation in comparison between models

Tags: regression

hope you could help.

i have the following specification:
y=a0+b*x+e

I conduct OLS regression for y1 and y2, while x are the same. Now I have the first R square> second R square.

How can I interpret it? Can I interpret it as
1) that x explains y1 better than x explains y2,
2) x has a larger effect for y1 while x has a smaller effect for y2

Or more generally, if I want to draw the above two interpretations, what criteria should I look at?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use R-squared to mean "What fraction of the variance in Y is explained by the model?" so that if the same x is used in two different models *of the same data* "y = f1(x)" and "y = f2(x)", my understanding is that I could use R-squared to tell me if model f1 or model f2 explains more of the variance in y *when using the same data set*.

Answer (score 0):

> I conduct OLS regression for y1 and y2, while x are the same. Now I
>   have the first R square> second R square.
>
> How can I interpret it?

You interpret it as the first model having more of its variance explained by *x*. It can *in general* be taken to mean that the [model fits the data better in your first case](https://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/regression-analysis-how-do-i-interpret-r-squared-and-assess-the-goodness-of-fit).